# Getting GDB to display the entirety of multi-line statements

Tags: gdb

GDB, at least as it's configured by default on my Ubuntu 9.04 box, doesn't handle multi-line statements well.  When I'm stepping through code, GDB only displays the last line of the current statement, even if that statement spans multiple lines.

I'm aware that I could use DDD or emacs as a frontend for GDB, but I'd prefer to solve this problem within GDB, if that's possible.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get GDB to do the right thing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is "no, there is no way to get gdb to do what you want".
The line info in the symbol tables associates each code instruction  with a single
source line (not a source statement).  gdb has no way of knowing that several 
source lines are associated with the same source statement.

Answer (score 8):

How about running GDB with the [text user interface](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html#TUI)?

```
gdb -tui
```

It makes a world of difference to the ease of use of GDB.

Comment: That's helpful, but I'd prefer just to use the normal interface, because my program's console output gets in the way of the tui.  Of course, I could redirect the text to another tty, but...I really just want GDB to do Do The Right Thing.